# How do I link a class return value to an external API documentation site using phpDocumentor?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

When generating documentation with phpDocumentor, if @param, @return value is a class in your project like:

```
@return My\Awesome\Class
```

phpdoc will automatically link My\Awesome\Class to the documentation for that class. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have it link to the documentation for a vendor class, i.e. make:

```
@return \Doctrine\Collection\Collections\ArrayCollection
```

link to http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.5/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html. The closest solution I've been able to figure out is to have phpdoc generate documentation for the all of the vendor libraries as well, which seems less than ideal.

Comment: That's what I'm using temporarily, but it's not what I would prefer. According to the phpdoc docs, I think what I want **should** be possible (see "external-class-documentation" under http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/configuration.html#transformer) but I can't get it to work.